# Need to set focus on the Close Button on tab press on Remove Button. But instead, focus is moving to input field which is below the close button

Tags: javascript, html

My function is :

```
function setFocus() {
    var c = $('.close');  // Extracting close class

    $('#RemoveButton').keydown(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            c[0].focus(); // focus should set on first close button. 
        }
    })
}
```

Goal is to set focus on the Close Button on tab press on Remove Button. But instead of close Button, focus is moving to input field which is below the close button. How to make focus on Close Button?

Comment: Add more code please.

Comment: Show your relevant markup. As far as I can tell, you don't need JavaScript here, just use the [`tabindex` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: Add your HTML code too please.